# Sharepoint Calculated Data

Tags: sharepoint

i have two columns in my sharepoint list

[Cluster Name] and [Host Name]

I wanted to implement a calculated sharepoint data for a [Cluster Name] column like if the field is blank it needs to have the first 3 characters from Hostname with an suffix of STANDALONE at end, can any one help me out on this, here's what i have till now, but when i try this it gives an error

=IF(ISBLANK([Cluster Name]),(UPPER(LEFT([Host Name],3))-STANDALONE),)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for IF is

IF(TEST,True, False)

But in your formula you're missing the false part.

Also - STANDALONE is a string - but you don't have any quotes.

Finally you're trying to concatenate strings together using - but it should be an &

So

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Cluster Name]),(UPPER(LEFT([Host Name],3))-STANDALONE),)
```

should be

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Cluster Name]),UPPER(LEFT([Host Name],3)) & "STANDALONE",[Cluster Name])
```

Check out the [MSDN Calculated field formula](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx) or [this one](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/examples-of-common-formulas-HA001160947.aspx) or the [Calculated Column Cheat Sheet](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/05/sharepoint-calculated-column-cheat-sheet/) for some examples and syntax.

*(Disclaimer - the last one is a link to my companies website and requires an email registration to download the cheat sheet pdf)*